# What is this daemon process using so much CPU?

Tags: services, dbus

As per the screengrab, this is puzzling, to me at least. I haven't noticed this running before, just the past few days. This is a workstation Ubuntu 18.04 current updates as of this morning. Interestingly, these processes stop if I open up System Monitor. Otherwise:

[image: Htop showing daemon process]

Any ideas?

Update: OK after deleting the directory running from `/tmp`, it keeps regenerating. Any intrusion specialists here that can suggest a way to find the script that creates this in `/tmp`? I restored from 4 days back (my lastest restore point) but that didn't help. Must be hiding in my `/home`, you think?

Comment: If it's in `/tmp`, I'd bet a few unicorn points that your system's hacked and is running a cryptocurrency miner.

Comment: A *real* dbus-daemon would be spawned by the command `/usr/bin/dbus-daemon`, not something hiding in `/tmp`. Processes that pause when you open System Monitor could not be more suspicious!

Comment: @muru that was my thought too 'crypto-miner'. Agree too @user535733! I've deleted the run file. Any ideas how to find out what inserted it? /tmp requires elevated privs to write to.

Comment: @Dithers a `/tmp` that's not world-writable likely breaks a lot of things, so it's hard to tell. Did you check the file details before deleting it? Which user is the process running as? If it's your user, your browser or SSH probably got hacked.

Comment: @muru it was running as a user process, my user process.  :-/  I have backups as in 'Timeshift' backups, so I should be good to go back to a safe point in time. Thanks!

Comment: OK After trying to find the script starting the processing and failing, I did what I should have done 1st - Re-installed. Then I brought backups into ~home 1x1 to ensure they weren't containing the Trojan. Sofar, so good. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @Dithers Looks like you're ready to self-answer, when you have time...

Comment: @ZeissIkon thanks should have done this at the time. I'm going from memory, but it was one of the Kodi addons from an 'unofficial repo'. So be warned that many of those plugins that offer movies/shows could be malware too! I've learned my lesson.